# Are the Diablo 3 Patches on Console now simultaneously released with their PC counter part?

Tags: diablo-iii

Back in 2014 blizzard said that they would try to patch consoles as close as possible to their PC counter part. I have read an article that said that 2.1.2 was patched at the same time on PC and console.

Can anyone confirm weather or not 2.2 got released at the same time on console as it was on PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Patch 2.2 was first released for PC, PS4 and Xbox One](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/18642492/patch-220-now-live-4-7-2015).

As you can see by the link, Blizzard already answer this question on release of the patch.

Comment: Just as an FYI, it's important to keep in mind that while Blizzard has stated that they want to release patches at the same times, in some cases it might just not be possible, so if a patch goes live on one platform or another, there's no real reason to assume it's fully functional on another. At this rate Blizzard has to upkeep 4 versions of D3:ROS, all have slightly different features  (not including vanilla)